# makecert.exe - WS2012 fail to acquire a security provide from the issuer's certificate - Failed

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, makecert

I'm trying to create a new sel certificate in order to specify a duration different than the one created by default from an application.
Using the command:
makecert.exe -b 10/10/2015 -m 36 -n "CN=MYSERVER.domain.com" -sk "MYSERVER.domain.com" -sky "exchange" -sr localmachine -ss my -in "SelfSignedCA" -ir localmachine -is root

but system prevent me providing "Fail to acquire a security provide from the issuer's certificate - Failed".
I'm not so confident in creating the certificates...any help?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, stop using makecert.exe. It is no longer supported by Microsoft starting from Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2. Instead, you should use new functionality of certreq.exe utility. More details: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2012/08/14/rsa-key-blocking-is-here.aspx

Comment: hi crypto guy and thanks for your answer!
I had a look on the technet site and the tool seems to be stronger than makecert... but I'm finding some troubles in order to "map" old option statement (-sk , -ss, -sr, -in, -ir) on this new paradigm... Any suggestions? cheers